# Python module is installed, and in correct site-packages, but is still not found. Any idea how I could fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, modulenotfounderror

I'm having trouble getting my python program, using pyVim, to run on a Centos machine.  As far as I can tell, everything is installed correctly and in the right places, but it still claims to be not found.
This runs correctly on a different machine (with the same python/pip versions), on which I installed pyvim without incident, so the code should be good.

> $ python3.8 vm_status_check.py

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyVim'
```

> $ python3.8 -m pip install pyvim

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyvim in /home/lab-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.0.2)
```

> $ python3.8 -m site

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/lab-user/Mandalorian-Labs',
    '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/home/lab-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/lab-user/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/lab-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

> $ ls /home/lab-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

```
Pygments-2.7.1.dist-info     prompt_toolkit                  pygments               six.py
__pycache__                  prompt_toolkit-3.0.7.dist-info  pyvim                  wcwidth
docopt-0.6.2-py3.8.egg-info  pyflakes                        pyvim-3.0.2.dist-info  wcwidth-0.2.5.dist-info
docopt.py                    pyflakes-2.2.0.dist-info        six-1.15.0.dist-info
```

So, as far as I can tell, everything looks to be in order.  But "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyVim'" persists.  Could anything else be causing this?

Comment: Why the capital V?

Comment: It looks like you've installed a Python-based clone of the Vim editor, named `pyvim`, when you really meant to install a completely unrelated thing named `pyVim` that comes with [pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi).

Comment: Packages are case sensitive, you are trying to import pyVim when the package name you installed is pyvim. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was a bit of a red herring.  the package that was *actually* missing was pyvmomi, and installing that fixed the issue.